# NestJS - Validate/Serialize differently based on request shape

Tags: nestjs

I need to validate a request which might have 3 different shapes based on a property called "status" on the body, this would be needed for serialization as well

How would I do that ?

Requests body examples:

`{ "status" : "training", "trainingSetId": "dijado389828", "fileData": { "fileUrl": someurl, "nRows": 4000" } }`

`{ "status" : "test", "testSetId": "ddadfaax344x", "someOtherProp": "idk", "fileData": { "fileUrl": someurl, "nRows": 4000", "predictionFileUrl": someotherurl } }`

I'd be fine with making a class for each request type, but how would I conditionally use one or the other ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use for that a https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#object-schema-validation as follow:

```js
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class JoiValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private readonly schema: Object) {}

  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const { error } = this.schema.validate(value);
    if (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

where `schema` can be defined in different file, and can be passed as argument when you're using Pipe in controller, example of schema object:

```js
export const schema = Joi.object({
    status: Joi.string().valid('training', 'test'),
    rest_keys: Joi.any()
})
    .when(Joi.object({ status: Joi.exist() }).unknown(), {
        then: Joi.object({
            rest_key: Joi.valid('some_value or required')
        }),
        otherwise: Joi.object({
            a: Joi.valid('similar as above')
        })
});
```

You can read more about conditional validation using Joi here https://hapi.dev/family/joi/api/?v=17.0.2#anywhencondition-options

Comment: You've given a good answer but I was looking for an answer for class-validator, I probably should've specified,  I tought it was the standard for nest

Comment: But with class-validator will be hard to achieve your goal, btw Joi is also one of the nestjs way to validate input, but up2u